# How can I sum certain elements in a python list to meet specific conditions?

Tags: python, sum

I have a python list, similar to the following:

```
foo = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

I'd like to find a way to sum some of the list elements, provided the sum does not exceed a specific value, such as "7" in the list above.  I want it to find all the combinations that do not exceed "7".

I need it to return a result that looks something like:

```
[1, 2, 3]
[1, 4]
[2, 4]
[1, 5]
```

I'm aware I can already sum a complete list using *sum(foo)*, but I only want to sum part of the list.  I'm not aware of a way to introduce an if *sum(foo) < 7* argument that only sums some of the terms.

How would I do this?  Should I be using itertools.combinations?

Comment: Question for you: does the number of digits to sum have to be at least 2?

Comment: Yes, the number of digits needs to be at least two.  It does look like this is a duplicate question.  Here is the previous answer, which is very similar.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46942681/how-to-find-all-combinations-that-sum-up-to-at-most-a-constant

Comment: Well since I can't answer this one explicitly, this should get you started (apologies ahead of time for the formatting in the comments):

from itertools import combinations

foo = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

combos = []

for r in range(1,len(foo)):
 combos.append([','.join(map(str, comb)) for comb in combinations(foo, r) if sum(comb)<7])

Comment: Very elegant.  Nice answer.  I wish I could upvote it.  This is why StackOverflow is frustrating.  I tried to ask a valid question and I get downvotes.  Makes me not want to use the site anymore.

Comment: Shoot me an upvote on the comment and I'll be happy lol. Hope I got you started! And yes, sometimes it seems that people are quick to jump to a 'duplicate question' conclusion...

Comment: Didn't know I could upvote a comment.  Done.