# How to find all combinations that equal a given sum?

Tags: python, sum

In SQL I have a list of transaction types and a value.
Simple example below.

```
|-----------|--------|
| Tran.Type | Value  | 
|-----------|--------|
|     04    |   10   |
|-----------|--------|
|     07    |   10   |
|-----------|--------|
|     04    |   5    |
|-----------|--------|
|     01    |   8    | 
|-----------|--------|



|-----------------|
| Current Balance |
|-----------------|
|        13       |
|-----------------|
```

Goal is to sum values and get number 13.
In this example is easy to find that type 07 is negative.
So 10-10+5+8=13

But when number of transaction gets to 20 & 10 different types is quite difficult.
Also values are positive & negative.

So far I came up with this.

```
import itertools
numbers = list(map(int, input("Enter multiple values: ").split()))
expectedSum = int(input("Enter expected value: "))
result = [seq for i in range(len(numbers), 0, -1) for seq in 
itertools.combinations(numbers, i) if sum(seq) == expectedSum]
print (result)<code>
```

Any idea how can I incorporate type to result section? and if that type is an opposite value or not?

Comment: This is an interesting question. It could be simplified by stripping the SQL out of the Q, which will narrow down the problem. Consider starting the question with say, a list of tuples containing only the transaction type and value.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this problem is NP-hard - looks like Knapsack problem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem

Comment: Maybe dupe: [How to find all combinations that sum up to at most a constant?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46942681/674039)

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways to do this,  by using `CASE` in your SQL statement OR if you have a VERY large list then introduce a field which will contain +1 or -1 based on the Transaction Type, then when you are performing the values MULTIPLY the value and finally do a sum. Example, is here;

```
ALTER TABLE Tran ADD COLUMN tran_multiple INT default 1;

-- update each value as req.
UPDATE Tran set tran_multiple=-1 WHERE Tran.id = xxxx; 

SELECT sum (TranValue.Value * Tran.tran_multiple) as Val From TranValue 
    INNER JOIN Tran on TranValue.Type = Tran.Type
```

Here I am assuming that your table TranValue stores the values. Of course, you can use Group By clause `GROUP BY Tran.type` in your statement, along with `Tran.type` in your SELECT field list (for listing by Tran.Type & Values). Then writing a simple code should not be a problem.

Though, I would request you to refrain from using `VALUE` or `VALUES` in your SQL as it is very similar to the `RESERVED KEYWORDs` (*just a suggestion*)

I am not putting the `CASE` example here since you didn't specify which Database you are using (syntax varies) and also since you claim that there are a large number of types.

If you prefer coding instead of SQL, then the same can be done by defining a dictionary where each *type* holds +1 or -1 depending on the *type* and then when the user inputs the values you can multiply *type* and get it done.

Hope this helps.