# sum no greater than k in array

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, space-complexity

> Given an array of integers and an integer *k*
>
> Find the maximum sum possible from the given array that is less than or equal to *k*
>
> - **Example:**
>
>   array = 7,6,9,11
>   *k* = 25
> - **Answer:**
>
>   24
> - **Explanation:**
>
>   possible combinations:
>   size 1 = (7),(6),(9),(11)
>   size 2 = (6,7), (6,9), (6,11), (7,9), (7,11), (9,11)
>   size 3 = (6,7,9), (6,7,11), (6,9,11), (7,9,11)
>   size 4 : (6,7,9,11)
>
>   Among these possible combinations, the sum of items that is maximum and less than or equal to *k*=25 is (6,7,11)=24
> - **Constraints:**
>
>   size of the array is 1 to 40
>   value of *k* is 1 to 10<sup>9</sup>
>   value of items in the array are 1 to 10<sup>9</sup>

I am using the code mentioned in the [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41284951/largest-subset-whose-sum-is-less-than-equal-to-a-given-sum) :

```
def largest_subset(items, k):
    res = 0

    # We can form subset with value 0 from empty set,
    # items[0], items[0...1], items[0...2]
    arr = [[True] * (len(items) + 1)]

    for i in range(1, k + 1):
        # Subset with value i can't be formed from empty set
        cur = [False] * (len(items) + 1)

        for j, val in enumerate(items, 1):
            # cur[j] is True if we can form a set with value of i from
            # items[0...j-1]
            # There are two possibilities
            # - Set can be formed already without even considering item[j-1]
            # - There is a subset with value i - val formed from items[0...j-2]
            cur[j] = cur[j-1] or ((i >= val) and arr[i-val][j-1])
        if cur[-1]:
            # If subset with value of i can be formed store
            # it as current result
            res = i

        arr.append(cur)
    return res
```

It works for a small range of inputs but when input to the program is huge, the code is failing at line:  `cur = [False] * (len(items) + 1)` saying **Memory Error**.

I also tried another [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46942681/how-to-find-all-combinations-that-sum-up-to-at-most-a-constant)

```
def subset_sum(vals, target=0):
    sums = {0: [()]}  # key=sum, value=list of subsets for the sum
    if target in sums:
        yield from sums[target]  # annoying base case
    for val in vals:
        items = sums.items()  # don't change dict size during iteration
        sums = dict(items)
        for prev_sum, prev_subsets in items:
            sum_ = prev_sum + val
            subsets = [s + (val,) for s in prev_subsets]
            sums[sum_] = sums.get(sum_, []) + subsets
            if sum_ <= target:
                yield from subsets
```

It also fails with same error message at line : `subsets = [s + (val,) for s in prev_subsets]`

What is the correct approach to solve this problem.

Comment: So, what have **you** coded so far?

Comment: If this problem is from a programming challenge / practice site, or otherwise has a web page, please provide a link to that web page.

Comment: What does this have to do with Java?

Comment: This approach (used here for a different problem) might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21077763/smallest-number-that-cannot-be-formed-from-sum-of-numbers-from-array/21080133#21080133

Answer (score 1):

Modifying this answer: [Smallest number that cannot be formed from sum of numbers from array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21077763/smallest-number-that-cannot-be-formed-from-sum-of-numbers-from-array/21080133#21080133)

Use bitvectors to accomplish this.

Start with an empty bitvector b. Then for each element x in your array, do this:

b = b | b << x | 2^(x-1)

To be clear, the i'th element is set to 1 to represent the number i, and | x is setting the x'th element to 1.

In doing the above step (b = b | ...), truncate your revised b after k bits since we don't care about making larger values.

After you finish processing the array, the largest index of a set bit in b is your answer (counting from the right, starting at 1).

In this example, for [4,13,2,3,1], we can make all values up to 23, other than 11 & 12.

1. b=0
2. process 4: b = b | b<<4 | 1000 = 1000
3. process 13: b = b | b<<13 | 1000000000000 = 10001000000001000
4. process 2: b = b | b<<2 | 10 = 1010101000000101010
5. process 3: b = b | b<<3 | 100 = 1011111101000101111110
6. process 1: b = b | b<<1 | 1 = 11111111111001111111111

There's a set bit at every index that can be made by summing a subset of the input array.

This would still work but would need modification if the input array had negative numbers.